# Unexpected Lambda behaviour

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

I am doing a POC on AWS Lambda. Lambda is exhibiting unexpected behavior.

Lambda code is as follows

```
var DB = require('../util/DB')
let response;

exports.lambda_handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    console.log("Starting");
    try {
        var connection = await DB.dbConnection();
        connection.release();
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello world'
            })
        }
        console.log(response)
        callback(null, response)
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        callback(error, null)

    }
    console.log("Sending Response")
    callback(null, response)
};
```

DB.js is

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

let pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    port: "3306",
    database: database,
    multipleStatements: true
});

pool.on('enqueue', function () {
    console.error('runQry-Waiting for available connection callback');
});

function getConnection() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("\n\nerror")
                reject(err)
            } else {
                console.log("\n\nresolve")
                resolve(connection)
            }
          });
    })
}
```

When I execute the lambda, it prints out "Starting", "resolve", response, and "Sending Response" in a console and then waits until timeout.

I tried commenting out "var connection.." and "conection..". It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have made some small mistakes here:-

1. DB.dbConnection() is not a function in DB.js so i guess code is rather incomplete.
2. You have to close the pool in order to tell lambda that it is safe to end the transaction use pool.end(/*callback*/ fn()=>{}).
3. I highly recommend you to use context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; to tell lambda to stop when you issue the callback as the lambda funciton will always go until it hits the timeout limit you set.

Happy Coding :)

Edit :- use this for refernce for timeout related issues https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html